# getting error that says expected ';' but got '}' please some one help

Tags: solidity, javascript

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

//SPDX-Licence-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
contract ChatApp{
    // USER STRUCT
    struct user{
        string name;
        friend[] friendlist;
    }
    struct friend{
        address pubkey;
        string name;
    }

    struct message{
        address sender;
        uint256 timestamp;
        string msg;
    }
    struct AllUserStruck{
        string name;
        address accountAddress;
    }
    AllUserStruck[] getAllUsers;
    mapping(address => user) userlist;
    mapping(bytes32 => message[]) allMessages;
    function checkUserExists(address pubkey) public view returns(bool){
        return bytes(userList[pubkey].name).length > 0;
    }
    //CREATE ACCOUNT
    function createAccount(string calldata name) external {
        require(theUserExists(msg.sender) == false, "User already exists");
        require(bytes(name).length>0, "Username cannot be empty");
        userList[msg.sender].name = name;
        getAllUsers.push(AllUsersStruck(name, msg.sender));
    }
    //GET USERNAME
    function getUsername(address pubkey) external view returns(string memory){
        
    }
    function addFriend(address friend_key, string calldata name) external{
        require(checkUserExists(msg.sender), "Create an account first");
        require(checkUserExists(friend_key), "User is not registered!");
        require(msg.sender|=friend_key, "Users cannot add themselves as friend");
        require(checkAlreadyFriend(msg.sender, friend_key)== false, "These users are already friends");

        _addFriend(msg.sender, friend_key, name);
        _addFriend(friend_key, msg.sender, userList[msg.sender].name);
    }
    //checkAlreadyFriends
    function checkAlreadyFriend (address pubkey1, address pubkey2) internal view returns(bool){
        if(userList[pubkey1].friendList.length > userList[pubkey2].friendList.length){
            address tmp = pubkey1;
            pubkey1 = pubkey2;
            pubkey = tmp;
        } 
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < userList[pubkey].friendList.length; i++){
            if(userList[pubkey1].friendList[i].pubkey == pubkey2)return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    function _addFriend(address me, address friend_key, string memory name) internal{
        friend memory newFriend = friend(friend_key, name);
        userList[me].friendList.push(newFriend);
    }
    //GET MY FRIEND
    function getMyFriendList() external view returns(friend[] memory){
        return userList[msg.sender].friendList;
    }
    //get chat code
    function _getChatCode(address pubkey1, address pubkey2) internal pure returns(bytes32){
        if(pubkey1 < pubkey2){
            return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(pubkey1, pubkey2));
        } else return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(pubkey1, pubkey2));
    }
    //SEND MESSAGE
    function sendMessage(address friend_key, string calldata _msg ) external{
        require(checkUserExists(msg.sender), "Create an account first");
        require(checkUserExists(friend_key), "User is not registered");
        require(checkAlreadyFriends(msg.sender, friend_key), "You are not friend with the given user");
        bytes32 chatCode = _getChatCode(msg.sender, friend_key);
        message memory newMsg = message(msg.sender, block.timestamp, _msg);
        allMessages[chatCode].push(newMsg);
    }
    //READ MESSAGE
    function readMessage (address friend_key) external view returns(message[] memory){
        bytes32 chatCode = _getChatCode(msg.sender, friend_key);
        return allMessages[chatCode];
    }
    function getAllUsers() public view returns(AllUsersStruck[]-memory){
        return getAllUsers
    }
    

}
```

Comment: The error says you are missing a `;` in some place.

Comment: I checked the full code didn't find it can you help

Answer (score 0):

At least the function `getAllUsers` has several errors: an extra `-` (dash), missing a `;`.

```
AllUserStruck[] _getAllUsers;


function getAllUsers() public view returns(AllUsersStruck[] memory) {
    return _getAllUsers;
};
```

Comment: Also there is an array with that name so it will fail

Answer (score 0):

```
//There are various typos in this code and incorrect naming maybe correcting them might help like:

require(theUserExists(msg.sender) == false, "User already exists");  
      //statement should be                             
require(checkUserExists(msg.sender) == false, "User already exists");

`require(msg.sender|=friend_key, "Users cannot add themselves as friend");` 
//replace it with this
 `require(msg.sender != friend_key, "Users cannot add themselves as friend");`

`function checkAlreadyFriend (address pubkey1, address pubkey2) internal view returns(bool);`                     
//Function name is missing `s`               
`function checkAlreadyFriends (address pubkey1, address pubkey2) internal view returns(bool);`
// these are some I noticed you might want to check the code properly. if you have written it by yourself recheck the naming of the functions;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// here is your full corrected code It compiled without any errors check after deploying t=it on the frontend if it is working properly or not and do share the final results

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract ChatApp {
    // USER STRUCT
    struct User {
        string name;
        Friend[] friendList;
    }
    struct Friend {
        address pubkey;
        string name;
    }

    struct Message {
        address sender;
        uint256 timestamp;
        string msg;
    }

    struct AllUserStruct {
        string name;
        address accountAddress;
    }

    AllUserStruct[] public allUsers;
    mapping(address => User) public userList;
    mapping(bytes32 => Message[]) public allMessages;

    function checkUserExists(address pubkey) public view returns (bool) {
        return bytes(userList[pubkey].name).length > 0;
    }

    //CREATE ACCOUNT
    function createAccount(string memory name) external {
        require(checkUserExists(msg.sender) == false, "User already exists");
        require(bytes(name).length > 0, "Username cannot be empty");
        userList[msg.sender].name = name;
        allUsers.push(AllUserStruct(name, msg.sender));
    }

    //GET USERNAME
    function getUsername(address pubkey) external view returns (string memory) {
        return userList[pubkey].name;
    }

    function addFriend(address friend_key, string memory name) external {
        require(checkUserExists(msg.sender), "Create an account first");
        require(checkUserExists(friend_key), "User is not registered!");
        require(
            msg.sender != friend_key,
            "Users cannot add themselves as friend"
        );
        require(
            checkAlreadyFriend(msg.sender, friend_key) == false,
            "These users are already friends"
        );

        _addFriend(msg.sender, friend_key, name);
        _addFriend(friend_key, msg.sender, userList[msg.sender].name);
    }

    //checkAlreadyFriends
    function checkAlreadyFriend(address pubkey1, address pubkey2)
        internal
        view
        returns (bool)
    {
        if (
            userList[pubkey1].friendList.length >
            userList[pubkey2].friendList.length
        ) {
            address tmp = pubkey1;
            pubkey1 = pubkey2;
            pubkey2 = tmp;
        }

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < userList[pubkey1].friendList.length; i++) {
            if (userList[pubkey1].friendList[i].pubkey == pubkey2) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function _addFriend(
        address me,
        address friend_key,
        string memory name
    ) internal {
        Friend memory newFriend = Friend(friend_key, name);
        userList[me].friendList.push(newFriend);
    }

    //GET MY FRIEND
    function getMyFriendList() external view returns (Friend[] memory) {
        return userList[msg.sender].friendList;
    }

    //get chat code
    function _getChatCode(address pubkey1, address pubkey2)
        internal
        pure
        returns (bytes32)
    {
        if (pubkey1 < pubkey2) {
            return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(pubkey1, pubkey2));
        } else return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(pubkey2, pubkey1));
    }

    //SEND MESSAGE
    function sendMessage(address friend_key, string memory _msg) external {
        require(checkUserExists(msg.sender), "Create an account first");
        require(checkUserExists(friend_key), "User is not registered");
        require(
            checkAlreadyFriend(msg.sender, friend_key),
            "You are not friend with the given user"
        );
        bytes32 chatCode = _getChatCode(msg.sender, friend_key);
        Message memory newMsg = Message(msg.sender, block.timestamp, _msg);
        allMessages[chatCode].push(newMsg);
    }

    //READ MESSAGE
    function readMessage(address friend_key)
        external
        view
        returns (Message[] memory)
    {
        bytes32 chatCode = _getChatCode(msg.sender, friend_key);
        return allMessages[chatCode];
    }

    function getAllUsers() public view returns (AllUserStruct[] memory) {
        return getAllUsers();
    }
}
```